# ClickOnce Application is Requiring Administrator Password

Tags: security, clickonce, partial, trust

My previous employer has been using a website that I built for a few years. Recently, I started rewriting it to be a windows forms application with ClickOnce deployment.

To see if ClickOnce will work I created a blank test application to try on their computers. I have enabled ClickOnce security settings as partial trust with Local Intranet as where it will be installed from. When I try and run the application on one of their work computers I get a notification saying I need an administrator password.

Everything I can find online says ClickOnce applications do not required administrator approval to run if they are set to partial trust.

Anybody have any ideas on what I can do to make it run on their computers?

Comment: What version of windows do the work computers run? Is it asking for your admin password or is it warning you that you are running something that may not be trusted?

Comment: The computers are running Windows 7. It was definitely asking for an admin password after warning you of running something that is not trusted. I ended up going into my previous employers office to do some testing. Turns out the package I created was wanting to install the .NET framework even though it was already installed on the computer. After fixing that the program ran just fine.